# Get livedata latest value while testing view model

Tags: testing, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to unit test my viewmodel:

```
private val loginRepository: LoginRepository = LoginRepository()
    private val _loginSuccess = MutableLiveData<Resource<String>>()
    val loginSuccess : LiveData<Resource<String>>
        get() = _loginSuccess

fun login(credentials : RequestLogin){
    _loginSuccess.value = Resource.loading()
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _loginSuccess.postValue(loginRepository.login(credentials))
    }
```

With this:

```
@Test
fun login_success(){
    val loginRequest = RequestLogin("username", "test")
    val app:Application = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
    PreferencesHelper.init(app)
    val viewModel = LoginViewModel(app)
    viewModel.loginSuccess.observeForever(dataObserver)

    runBlocking {
        viewModel.login(loginRequest)
        assertEquals(viewModel.loginSuccess.getOrAwaitValue(), Resource.success("OK"))
    }

    viewModel.loginSuccess.removeObserver(dataObserver)
}
```

But everytime i'm getting just the first value of the liveData object Resource.loading() instead of the one obtained with the postValue method.

How can i ignore the result of the first liveData update and just get the final one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runBlocking` executes and waits for completion for the block you pass to it, in this case it is

```
viewModel.login(loginRequest)
assertEquals(viewModel.loginSuccess.getOrAwaitValue(), Resource.success("OK"))
```

But this code does not have any suspend calls, so `runBlocking` does not have any effect here. In particular it does not affect the `viewModelScope.launch` call.

There are a couple of ways to test this code. I would suggest using [kotlinx-coroutines-test](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/) library. It provides [TestCoroutineDispatcher](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-test-coroutine-dispatcher/) which is very convenient in this case.

`viewModelScope` uses `Dispatchers.Main` dispatcher by default, so you need to replace it with `TestCoroutineDispatcher`. E.g. you can create a simple test rule:

```
class CoroutineTestRule(val dispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()) : TestWatcher() {

    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

Then apply it to your test:

```
@get:Rule
var coroutineTestRule: CoroutineTestRule = CoroutineTestRule()
```

And use it like this

```
@Test
fun login_success(){
   ...
   viewModel.login(loginRequest)
   coroutineTestRule.dispatcher.advanceUntilIdle()
   assertEquals(viewModel.loginSuccess.getOrAwaitValue(), Resource.success("OK"))
   ...
}
```

And here is a bit of how it works:

1. `CoroutineTestRule` replaces `Dispatcher.Main` with the `CoroutineTestRule.dispatcher`
2. Your viewmodel launches a login job, using `viewModelScope`, which uses the same `CoroutineTestRule.dispatcher`
3. `coroutineTestRule.dispatcher.advanceUntilIdle()` makes the dispatcher to execute all outstanding tasks, so it will execute all coroutines, which are using this dispatcher and are ready to be executed.

There is also very convenient `advanceTimeBy` method on `TestCoroutineDispatcher` which allows you to fast-forward and skip e.g. delay calls.